# R: How to separate values only after the second space

Tags: r, separator, strsplit

I have a column with different names:

```
X <- c("Ashley, Tremond WILLIAMS, Carla", "Claire, Daron", "Luw, Douglas CANSLER, Stephan")
```

After the second space, it starts the name of the second person. For instance, Ashley, Tremond is a person and WILLIAMS, Carla another one.

I have tried:

```
strsplit(X, "\\,\\s|\\,|\\s")
```

but it divides by all the spaces, so i get:

```
strsplit(X, "\\,\\s|\\,|\\s")
[[1]]
[1] "Ashley"   "Tremond"  "WILLIAMS" "Carla"   

[[2]]
[1] "Claire" "Daron" 

[[3]]
[1] "Luw"     "Douglas" "CANSLER" "Stephan"
```

How can I separate only after the first space, so I get?:

```
[1] "Ashley, Tremond"  "WILLIAMS, Carla"   

[[2]]
[1] "Claire, Daron" 

[[3]]
[1] "Luw, Douglas" "CANSLER, Stephan"
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: `strsplit(X, "[^,] ")` gives the desired output. It splits the string where a space is not preceded by a comma.

Comment: You'll want to unlist it to maintain the vector: `unlist(strsplit(X, split = "[A-z] [A-z]"))`

Comment: @RyanMorton , if you skip the `unlist` call, it preserves the grouping level of names in the original input, and matches the expected output

Comment: The expected outcome was edited into the post after my original response, but yes. strsplit() returns a list.

Comment: @ykt  and Ryan thanks so much for your help, it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringr::str_match` with `^(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)?(?:\s+(.+))?` regex (see the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/XWtTln/1)):

```r
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "(?s)^(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)?(?:\\s+(.+))?")[,-1]
# => [1] "string I"                      "would like to split somewhere"
```

Also, you can use `utils::strcapture`:

```r
result <- utils::strcapture("^(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)?(?:\\s+(.+))?", x, list(left=character(), right=character()))
# > result
#        left                         right
#  1 string I would like to split somewhere
result$left
# => [1] "string I"
result$right
# => [1] "would like to split somewhere"
```

The `^(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)?(?:\s+(.+))?` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)?` - an optional group 1:

  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\s+\S+)?` - an optional occurrence of one or more whitespaces and then one or more non-whitespaces
- `(?:\s+(.+))?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(.+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Note that it is not safe to use `stringr::str_split` here as the only way to use it is with a constrained-width lookbehind:

```r
str_split(x, "(?<=^\\S{1,1000}\\s{1,1000}\\S{1,1000})\\s+")
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "string I"                      "would like to split somewhere"
```

Since in a constrained-width lookbehind one can't use `+` or `*` quantifiers, all you can do is use limiting quantifiers with declared min and max arguments, `{1,1000}`. Here, 1000 chars is the limit that you need to adjust based on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Of course @ytk's comment works, but in case you want to avoid the regex, 
you can be sneaky and do

```
df2 <- df %>%
  separate(col = X, into=c("person1a","person1b","person2a","person2b"),sep= " ") %>%
  unite(col = "person1", person1a, person1b, sep=" ") %>%
  unite(col = "person2", person2a, person2b, sep=" ")
```

which returns:

```
> df2
          person1          person2
1 Ashley, Tremond  WILLIAMS, Carla
2   Claire, Daron            NA NA
3    Luw, Douglas CANSLER, Stephan
```

p.s. I use `df <- data.frame(X = c("Ashley, Tremond WILLIAMS, Carla", "Claire, Daron", "Luw, Douglas CANSLER, Stephan"))` to make the input into a dataframe.

Comment: thanks but I writing the exact same code and it is not working for me, and I don't' really understand it, what does the %>% means?

Comment: @NataliaP it's a way of `piping` syntax , check out the `magrittr` package.